# MPI Merge sort error Signal code: Address not mapped (1)

Tags: c++, mpi

i'm trying to do a parallel merge sort using mpi but when i run code with "mpirun -np 2 --allow-run-as-root a.out" i obtain this output. also when i use "mpirun -np 4 --allow-run-as-root a.out"

```
Array disordinato: 44 41 82 8 1 34 60 64 40 31 47 44 78 90 80 57 6 6 39 73 29 15 34 67 75 18 7 49 20 38 8 17 31 42 77 84 77 38 0 69 69 47 13 99 37 45 56 44 51 47 17 33 14 4 52 89 22 59 39 95 49 99 12 32 42 89 68 71 79 68 40 0 15 6 0 53 51 8 49 55 56 18 88 70 22 40 60 97 51 51 92 53 50 56 37 44 97 6 15 77
Array ordinato:
0 0 0 1 4 6 6 6 6 7 8 8 8 12 13 14 15 15 15 17 17 18 18 20 22 22 29 31 31 32 33 34 34 37 37 38 38 39 39 40 40 40 41 42 42 44 44 44 44 45 47 47 47 49 49 49 50 51 51 51 51 52 53 53 55 56 56 56 57 59 60 60 64 67 68 68 69 69 70 71 73 75 77 77 77 78 79 80 82 84 88 89 89 90 92 95 97 97 99 99
Time: 0.0005664

[PcFissoWindows:00337] *** Process received signal ***
[PcFissoWindows:00337] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[PcFissoWindows:00337] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[PcFissoWindows:00337] Failing at address: 0x4e0000009d
[PcFissoWindows:00337] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7f1da996ef20]
[PcFissoWindows:00337] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20(ompi_info_finalize+0xd4)[0x7f1daa321254]
[PcFissoWindows:00337] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20(ompi_mpi_finalize+0x574)[0x7f1daa328264]
[PcFissoWindows:00337] [ 3] a.out(+0xbc5b)[0x7f1daac0bc5b]
[PcFissoWindows:00337] [ 4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f1da9951b97]
[PcFissoWindows:00337] [ 5] a.out(+0xb77a)[0x7f1daac0b77a]
[PcFissoWindows:00337] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node PcFissoWindows exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

can you help me? All code is here

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 100;
    int myid;
    int numprocs;
    int *data = new int[n];
    int buf;
    double timer_start;
    double timer_end;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    if (myid == 0)
    {
        buf = n / numprocs; //buf e' il numero di elementi cha avra' ogni processo

        cout << endl
             << "Array disordinato: ";
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            data[i] = rand() % n;
            cout << data[i] << " ";
        }

        timer_start = MPI_Wtime();

        cout << endl
             << endl;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int *recdata = new int[buf];

    MPI_Scatter(data, buf, MPI_INT, recdata, buf, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    mergeSort(recdata, buf);

        if (myid % 2 == 0)
        {
            int *tmp = new int[buf];
            MPI_Recv(tmp, buf, MPI_INT, myid+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            merge(recdata, tmp, buf);
        }
        else
        {
            MPI_Send(recdata, buf, MPI_INT, myid-1,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
```

array is ordered but, i think, i obtain error when i finalize parallel section

```
void merge(int *recdata, int *tmp, int buf)
{
    int *v1 = new int[buf];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf; i++)
    {
        v1[i] = recdata[i];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while ((i < buf) && (j < buf))
    {
        if (v1[i] < tmp[j])
        {
            recdata[i + j] = v1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            recdata[i + j] = tmp[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (j < buf)
    {
        for (k = j; k < buf; k++)
            recdata[k + i] = tmp[k];
    }
    else
    {
        for (k = i; k < buf; k++)
            recdata[k + j] = v1[k];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *recdata, int buf)
{
    int meta = buf / 2;
    if (meta > 0)
    {
        mergeSort(recdata, meta);              //analizzo prima meta' dell'array
        mergeSort(recdata + meta, buf - meta); //analizzo seconda meta' dell'array

        //classico merge
        int *tmp = new int[buf];

        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int j = meta;
        while (i < meta && j < buf)
        {
            if (recdata[i] < recdata[j])
            {
                tmp[k] = recdata[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp[k] = recdata[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while (i < meta)
        {
            tmp[k] = recdata[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }

        while (j < buf)
        {
            tmp[k] = recdata[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < buf; i++)
            recdata[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is the consequence of a memory corruption in your code. make sure not to write outside of your arrays.

Comment: resolved changing int *recdata = new int[buf]; to int *recdata = new int[n];